# Difference of julian timestamps in seconds

Tags: c

I have two julian timestamps in the format (YYYYDDDHHMISS) and I want to calculate difference between them  in seconds in C. Any idea.

Comment: One day has (24*60*60) seconds. Calculate the difference between the first parts of the dates (mind leap years) and multiply. Same thing for hours and minutes and seconds

Comment: Thanks pmg. Any idea about specific library function

Comment: Maybe [`strtol()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strtol.html) to convert a string to a number.

Comment: That number will be very very large.

Comment: Then isolate the parts of the number you care about -- you don't need any library function for that: just assignments from the original string to the copy(ies).

Answer (score 3):

You could use [strptime](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strptime) to parse the string into a tm structure and call [mktime](http://linux.die.net/man/3/mktime) to get a time_t which is exactly what you want to compare them.

Note: mktimes start date is limited to 1970 you should check whether it is useful or write your own function based on the tm-structure.

Comment: And then use `difftime` to compare them (since `time_t` isn't guaranteed to be an integer representation of the number of seconds since some fixed date).  Note that different platforms will have different epochs (start dates).  I've seen 1/1/1970, 1/1/1980, 1/1/2000 and even 1/1/1904 (pre-OS X Macintosh).